# Vmodel with Vuex not binding

Tags: vuex

I've followed the model of using get and then set within a computed property to make vmodel work with Vuex and the input of `<textarea>` but something isn't working and I'm not sure what it is.

I've got:

```
<textarea
          class="text-area size19"
          rows="10"
          v-model="userInput"
          aria-label="With textarea"
          placeholder="The more keywords you add, the better..."
        ></textarea>

 computed: {
   userInput: {
    get() {
    return this.$store.getters.userInput;
    },
    set(value) {
    this.$store.commit("updateUserInput", value);
  }
}
}
```

Then in .store there is a getter that just returns value and a mutation like this:

```
updateUserInput: (state, newUserInput) => {
  state.userInput = newUserInput;
}
```

Comment: can you provide more details - what exactly is happening? and if you can share the entire store.js file it will be much easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

My guesses here are

either:

```
updateUserInput: (state, newUserInput) => {
   Vue.set(state, 'userInput', newUserInput)
}
```

or:

```
getters: {
  userInput(state){return state.userInput}
},
```

but actually

```
computed: {
  userInput: {
    get: funciton(){
      return this.$store.state.userInput
    },
    set: function(newVal){
       this.$store.commit('updateUserInput', newVal)
    }
}
```